# Kubernetes ingress path forward to service endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to use a Kubernetes ingress object on my GKE cluster to send traffic to my frontend and backend services. The bit that I am unable to figure out how to forward traffic from a specific path of Ingress controller to a specific path of my backend service.

**# 1 - Ingress root path to frontend root path - Working Correctly**

`curl "ingress-ip"` to send traffic to my frontend

**# 2 - Ingress specific path to service specific path - Not Working**

`curl "ingress-ip/api/bpcalc/"` should send the traffic to my backend service at `/api/bpcalc/` path because my Go backend service is processing GET/POST requests with this specific endpoint.

When I tested with LoadBalancer service type it worked well for the backend service, but I guess this Ingress routing is not working in my case. I am quite new to Kubernetes and if required I can switch to nginx ingress controller as I have read about some annotation to rewrite ingress url, but I am not sure if that works what I am looking for.

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.ingress.name }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: {{ .Values.ingress.gke_static_ip }}
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.frontend.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.frontend.port }}
      - path: /api/bpcalc/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.backend.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.backend.port }}
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.container.name }}-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    repo: bpcalc
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: {{ .Values.container.port }}
```

**Updates**
When I tried with `pathType: Exact` and path: '/' for UI service, the ingress seems to be reaching to my frontend service but only the index.html page is returned instead of full React app. Any ideas what needs to be changed to make it working? I am using nginx in the final container to run the web app and here is my nginx.conf

```
server {

  listen 8080;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.frontend.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.frontend.port }}
      - path: /api/bpcalc
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.backend.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.backend.port }}
```

After this hit the any endpoint and also try with `curl "ingress-ip/api/bpcalc/`

Ref doc : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#create-ingress

Comment: so essentially you are asking about removing `*` from path.

Comment: yes remove that regex or * and give try without that.

Comment: Just tested it, doesn't seems to be working. The backend service is marked as unhealthy under 'Load balancing resources'. When I modified the backend service code yesterday to accept GET/POST connections at its root instead of endpoints, then only the ingress went to 'OK' state. Also, from the documentation its nowhere written that traffic will be routed to service endpoints, it only talks about routing traffic to services. So, I am interpreting: `ingress-ip/path` as hitting the service root path only where `path` is used for segregating backend services only. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: not sure what is error, with the endpoint but generally it works would hard to share some input without details. ideally don't touch LB and backend service as it gets auto-created by the ingress controller you can manage ingress and check.

Comment: I have some additional observation on the UI service and updated the main post. Do you have suggestions for the nginx.conf?